HandlerExceptionResolver in exception handler doesn't work
thank you for your time.
I use Spring boot 3.4.0 and I want to throw an exception in filter, but it doesn't work...
Everything is correct according to the breakpoints and logs, but my response body is empty.
The filter:
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, 
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        
        try {
            
            if (token.startsWith("Basic ")) {

                String codeId = request.getParameter("codeId");
                String text = request.getParameter("text");

                CaptchaCode captchaCode = new CaptchaCode(codeId, text, null);

                captchaCodeApplicationService.isCoptchaCodeValid(captchaCode);

            }
            ...
        
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, e);
        }
        
    }

}

The advice:
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handlerValidationException(ValidationException e, WebRequest request) {
        
        ExceptionDetails details = new ExceptionDetails(
                LocalDateTime.now(),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.name(),
                request.getDescription(false),
                e.getMessage()
                );
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(details, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    
}

The securityConfig:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecuirtyConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    UserApplicationService userApplicationService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtFilter;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        
        return httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(registry -> {
            registry.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll();
            registry.requestMatchers("/api/v1/users/**").permitAll();
            registry.anyRequest().authenticated();
        }).formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.permitAll())
                .csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfig -> httpSecurityCsrfConfig.disable())
                .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfig -> httpSecurityCorsConfig.disable())
                .sessionManagement(httpSecuritySessionConfig -> httpSecuritySessionConfig.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() throws Exception {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userApplicationService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() throws Exception {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}

And the method that throws exception:
public boolean isCoptchaCodeValid(CaptchaCode captchaCode) throws ValidationException {
    ...
}

And the response:



I quick test with the below code, gives me this body:
{"now":"2024-12-20T14:53:02.339526733","name":"BAD_REQUEST","description":"uri=/backend-spring-boot/graphiql","message":"Invalid token"}

ExceptionDetails
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public record ExceptionDetails(
        LocalDateTime now,
        String name,
        String description,
        String message) {
}

JwtAuthenticationFilter
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver;

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) {

        try {
            throw new ValidationException("Invalid token");
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, e);
        }
    }
}

ValidationException
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class ValidationException extends RuntimeException {
    public ValidationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

Update
Added my security config (relevant parts)
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/graphiql","/graphql").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .build();
    }


Thanks. I use spring security too. maybe after JwtAuthenticationFilter  calls an other filters. do you know it ?

@Albert: I'm also using Spring Security in the application I tested the above code with.

can you write here your security config too?

@Albert: Updated my answer with security config

@Albert: If you want to test with my code: https://github.com/roar-skinderviken/vicx-applications , module backend-spring-boot. Please note that you'll have to start the auth-server first: ./gradlew -p auth-server bootRun

Thanks a lot. My mistake was in security config. Thanks a lot :)
